# Why does my script report 'uninitialized value in eval "string"?

Tags: perl, warnings, eval

I am getting this warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value in eval \"string\" at myscript.pl line 57.
```

When I run this code:

```
eval;
{
        `$client -f $confFile -i $inputFile -o $outputFile`;
};

if( $@ )
{
        # error handling here ...
}
```

What is causing the error?

How can I fix the underlying cause? (Or otherwise suppress the warning?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a semicolon after `eval`.

Comment: And eval takes $_ as its default argument.  Which lets you do things like:
perl -wnE'say eval'
but otherwise is not particularly useful.

Answer (score 12):

The eval here would do absolutely nothing anyway. Backticks never throw errors. It's not `$@` but `$?` that you want to check.

Also, if you're throwing away the result, it may be a cleaner idea to use [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). e.g.

```
system($client, '-f', $confFile, '-i', $inputFile, '-o', $outputFile) and do {
    #error handling here...
};
```